# How do I select rows with MAX(datetime) and also get min values for a column?

Tags: mysql

My table is like this (np_capacity):

```
id  tower  datetime             capacity
---|----|---------------------|----------
1  | A  | 2016-05-29 09:02:41 | 34676
2  | B  | 2016-05-29 09:02:41 | 10736
5  | C  | 2016-05-29 09:02:41 | 55664
3  | D  | 2016-05-29 09:02:41 | 32622
4  | A  | 2016-05-29 13:08:38 | 5474
6  | B  | 2016-05-29 13:08:38 | 20692
7  | C  | 2016-05-29 13:08:38 | 134802
8  | D  | 2016-05-29 13:08:38 | 4754
```

I want to select all the tower with the max date then for those towers I also want the min capacity value in the table.

Result would be:

```
id  tower  datetime             capacity   MinCapacity
---|----|---------------------|----------|-------------
4  | A  | 2016-05-29 13:08:38 | 5474     | 5474
6  | B  | 2016-05-29 13:08:38 | 20692    | 10736
7  | C  | 2016-05-29 13:08:38 | 134802   | 55664
8  | D  | 2016-05-29 13:08:38 | 4754     | 4754
```

What I have is this but it doesnt always give my the correct min values.

```
SELECT npc.*, groupedcap.MinCapacity
FROM np_capacity npc
INNER JOIN
(SELECT tower, MAX(date) AS MaxDate
FROM np_capacity
GROUP BY tower) groupednpc 
ON npc.tower = groupednpc.tower 
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT tower, MIN(capacity) AS MinCapacity
FROM np_capacity
GROUP BY tower) groupedcap 
ON npc.tower = groupedcap.tower 
AND npc.date = groupednpc.MaxDate
```

Comment: How about LEAST() ???

Comment: What would `LEAST()` help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a subselect to calculate the min capacity, and the max date. Then, join with the table to get other fields.

```
select npc.*, calc.minCapacity
from (
    select tower, max(datetime) maxDate, min(capacity) minCapacity
    from np_capacity
    group by tower
) calc
join np_capacity npc on (npc.tower = calc.tower
                         and npc.datetime = npc.maxDate)
```

This request select all towers, and for each the maxdatetime and mincapacity.

If you want just the towers with the maxdatetime, you can use :

```
select npc.*, (select min(c2.capacity) from np_capacity c2 
               where c2.tower = npc.tower) minCapacity
from (select max(datetime) maxDatetime from np_capacity) c1
join np_capacity npc on (npc.datetime = c1.maxDatetime)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes I want only towers with maxdatetime and was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `a`.`id`,`a`.`tower`,`a`.`datetime`,`a`.`capacity`,(SELECT MIN(`b`.`capacity`) 
FROM `np_capacity` `b` WHERE `b`.`tower`=`a`.`tower` ) AS `MinCapacity` FROM `np_capacity` `a` 
WHERE `a`.`datetime`=(SELECT MAX(`datetime`) FROM `np_capacity`);
```

Test the above query on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5c400/72)

Answer (score 0):

Another answer is by using order by and limit 1 in sub query :

```
select t1.*,(select capacity from np_capacity t3 
  where t1.tower=t3.tower 
  order by capacity limit 1) mincapacity  
  from np_capacity t1 where  
 datetime=(select datetime from np_capacity
  order by datetime desc limit 1);
```

Test it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5c400/83/0)